# Etiquette for awarding bounty if none of the answers address the question completely but found to be equally useful

Tags: discussion, bounties, etiquette

*This may be a too-localized question but I still request an answer*.

---

I offered a bounty on the question [“Show notifications” is greyed out for some apps. What's causing it and how do I change it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120169/show-notifications-is-greyed-out-for-some-apps-whats-causing-it-and-how-do-i) worth 100 points. There are three points in the question which needs to be answered. In my bounty note, I explicitly mentioned that "*Point 1 and 2 specifically needs to be addressed in detail.*".

So far, I've received two good answers, one dealing with point 3 in detail and the other with point 2 and partially with point 1. None of the answers covers all the three points at a time.

My question is, do we have or what should be the etiquette for awarding bounty in cases where all the answers addresses the question equally or not completely?

I already upvoted both the answers; [I cannot split my bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261422/is-it-possible-to-divide-up-bounty-points) and  [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120417/96277) is already [eligible for automatic half-bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/286110).

I'm confused, that's why I asked the question here.

Comment: Don't award it?

Comment: @Tim, right. I forgot to mention that I want to award the bounty.

Comment: Why do you want to?

Comment: Because the answers there are worth enough to have at least half of the bounty. The dilemma is (since I can't split bounty) which one to award it.

Comment: You might want to accept the answer that answers part 3, and award the bounty to the answer adressing part 1&2. Rationale: the answer in part 3 doesn't really answer the request in the bounty, though it was helpful.

Comment: @wythagoras Thanks! Sounds reasonable to me. If no better option shows up in the comments in the next two days I'll consider your comment to award bounty and accept an answer during the grace period.